# DevStack installation fails due to PyYAML

Tags: centos, openstack, devstack

I am attempting to install DevStack on a CentOS system. I have performed the necessary setup for running stack.sh, but when I run it I am getting the following failure:

```
Installing collected packages: PyYAML, zipp, importlib-metadata, stevedore, colorama, pyperclip, cmd2, pyparsing, cliff, future, stestr, os-testr
  Attempting uninstall: PyYAML
    Found existing installation: PyYAML 5.3
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'PyYAML'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
+inc/python:pip_install:1                  exit_trap
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:489                  local r=1
++./stack.sh:exit_trap:490                  jobs -p
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:490                  jobs=
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:493                  [[ -n '' ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:499                  '[' -f '' ']'
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:504                  kill_spinner
+./stack.sh:kill_spinner:399               '[' '!' -z '' ']'
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:506                  [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:507                  echo 'Error on exit'
Error on exit
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:509                  type -p generate-subunit
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:512                  [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:515                  /usr/bin/python3.6 /opt/stack/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
ebtables v1.8.4 (nf_tables): table `broute' is incompatible, use 'nft' tool.

+./stack.sh:exit_trap:524                  exit 1
```

Researching this on the Internet, I have learned that this failure apparently occurs when python's pip3 commamd attempts to uninstall something that was installed using distutils (including, apparently, PyYAML). I also see that somewhere in stack.sh PyYAML gets installed, then later an attempt is made to uninstall it which fails!

I have also looked at the setup.py script that comes with Devstack, but that script apparently does not use distutils. It is used elsewhere during the PyYAML install, but  cannot find where it is.

Worse, there are workarounds (including using the --ignore-installed option for PIP), but I am not seeing where to place that option in stack.sh or any of the other files I have seen.

As things stand, stack.sh looks to be unusable. It is incapable of installing Devstack because of this problem.

Has anyone found a way to install Devstack and get around this problem? Is there an alternative to stack.sh? To devstack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem:

Do not use Devstack. Use Packstack.

I have even posted a bug report on this problem for Devstack. It doesn't appear that it is going to be fixed in the near future. Consequently, those seeking to create a development installation should use Packstack. I was able to install and run Openstack with Packstack using the instructions provided in:

https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-openstack-centos-8-with-packstack/